# How do I properly provide arg for many *.jar files in -cp argument for compilation on Unix?

Tags: java, compilation, javac, debian-stretch

I have a git repository which pulls down .java files to a production server when a push is made to a specific branch. (Working) I'm running Debian 9 with the openJDK package. (jdk 1.8.0)

I've decided to compile the new .java files on the server, then execute them. My issue is that while specifying the -cp arg as "lib/*.jar", during compilation I get: error package jar.example.class does not exist import jar.example.class;

And so forth for each reference to any information referenced from another .lib file.

**Important:**
The closest I've gotten is this command, which produces no output but does not compile the entire project.

- javac -classpath "bin:lib/*.jar" -d "bin/" "src/com/ruse/GameServer.java"

**For example:** in /server/bin/com/ruse/net/packet/impl/ the .class file is older than the corresponding ItemActionPacketListener.java file in /server/src/com/ruse/net/packet/impl/

- I am running this command in the /home/rsps/server directory.
- The .jar files exist in /home/rsps/server/lib folder.
- The .src files exist in /home/rsps/server/src folder.
- The .bin files are expected to output in /home/rsps/server/bin folder.
- The "main" class is void Main found in src/com/ruse/GameServer.java

Here's an image of the folder structure:
[image: folder structure]

For reference, here is the command I have been using to run the server (which works)

- java -server -Xmx2148m -classpath bin:lib/* com.ruse.GameServer

I've tried providing the -cp or -classpath arguments in different ways, however, javac seems to fail to reference the .jar files during compilation.

Here are the various javac commands I've tried:

- javac -classpath "lib/*.jar" -d "bin/" "src/com/ruse/GameServer.java"
- javac -sourcepath /home/rsps/server/src/*.java -classpath classes:lib/*.jar -d bin
- javac -classpath "lib/*.jar" -d "bin/" -sourcepath "src/" "src/com/ruse/GameServer.java"
- javac -cp "lib/:lib/*" -d "bin/" -sourcepath "src/" "src/com/ruse/GameServer.java"
- javac -cp .:/lib/*.jar: -d "bin/" "src/com/ruse/GameServer.java"

I expected the output to be the fresh .class files, however the actual results have all been a variation of below:

- javac -classpath "lib/*.jar" -d "bin/" "src/com/ruse/GameServer.java"

results in:

> symbol:   class ChannelBuffer
>
> location: class PacketBuilder
>
> src/com/ruse/world/World.java:11: error: package com.google.common.util.concurrent does not exist
>
> import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ThreadFactoryBuilder;
>
> ```
>                                    ^
> ```
>
> src/com/ruse/util/Misc.java:26: error: package org.jboss.netty.buffer does not exist
>
> import org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffer;
>
> ```
>                         ^
> ```
>
> src/com/ruse/util/Misc.java:750: error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
>    public static String readString(ChannelBuffer buffer) {
>
>                                    ^
> ```
>
> symbol:   class ChannelBuffer
>
> location: class Misc
>
> src/com/ruse/world/content/dialogue/DialogueManager.java:6: error: package com.google.gson does not exist
>
> import com.google.gson.Gson;
>
> ```
>                  ^
> ```

Comment: Have you tried `javac -classpath "bin/*:lib/*" -d "bin/" src/com/ruse/GameServer.java`?

Comment: Thank you @OleksandrShpota I appreciate your efforts however they yielded [similar results](https://i.imgur.com/rbnhe33.png).

Comment: @GhostCat the budget for this project is $15. It's built on open-source code I publish myself. What's wrong with that? Not like it's hard to decompile a maven built .jar file anyway?

Comment: Fact is: there's no vast difference in "security" between straight a /src/ folder and a freshly built unobfuscated maven JAR. (Which is clearly the implication here.) Anyone with the tools and the mindset can prove you wrong. I think you know that assertion is in vain of logic. Stop virtue signalling.

Comment: See, you're still assuming it's set up stupidly and it comes off as condescending. The server does not PUSH in this application, ever. Fetch, then pull only by design. I do not deceive you.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept! I also deleted the no longer required comments, and suggest that you see what can go away, too. So that future reader can focus on the essentials here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A distinct non answer: you are talking about a real world project and requirements.

In the real world, you don't invoke javac manually. Instead you use a build system like maven or gralde. You define a project structure which includes the required libraries.

And then you let the build system do all the pesky details. 
Anything else means: you spending efforts to create your own deficient build system.

So: do not reinvent the wheel! This problem is solved, and whatever you come up with will be less powerful and much more error prone than such mature build systems.

Update: when your team prefers to follow less efficient strategies, and you don't have any leverage, then the best option is to lead by example. Like: create a working build setup and project definition using gradle. Then show your team mates how nicely that setup works with eclipse. How you can use it to keep full control of what gets build, and when and how.

People are often nervous about changes, but they are often open when you can show them the advantages of a working solution!

Comment: Thanks, I understand your point, perhaps I have made things more difficult then they need to be. Unfortunately I cannot envoke Gradle or Maven dependencies on the project because the other developers are unwilling to integrate it. Seriously. They've suggested I move into a Windows VPS and run eclipse myself to compile.

Comment: Is there any chance you know of a Java library that would be suitable for this sort of building?

Comment: I believe [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) may be the sort of tool I'm looking for... Investigating...

Comment: Ant is like the last millennium solution to the things that you nowadays do with maven or gradle. And note: you can use both tools without the tool pulling dependencies from the internet. Anyhow, if your team mates are that, sorry, amateurs, you can only do two things: escalate to management or move on.

Comment: Bear in mind that Apache Ant is the predecessor to Apache Maven.  If your coworkers won't use Maven, you likely won't win them over with Ant either.

Comment: Alright stackoverflow, what do you think about just pushing compiled .class files with the .java files? I have had them ignored in my git repo, but that is a ...plausible solution under the circumstances.